# TeamCity test failure statistics with REST API

Tags: teamcity

There is an option in TeamCity to view aggregated most common failed tests.

Projects -> (select proj) -> Current Problems (tab) -> View tests failed within the last 120hrs

Is it possible to get the info about most common failing tests via TeamCity REST API?

Answer (score 1):

The following [REST API request](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API#RESTAPI-Tests) returns currently failing tests in project:

```
http://teamcity/app/rest/testOccurrences?locator=affectedProject:<projectId>,currentlyFailing:true
```